# syntax error in js task

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

I am trying to finish a small js task...wrote the code but i am getting syntax error... 
can you guys tell me what error is in it

Finish the james object by adding properties to it. His job should be "programmer" and should have a married property set to false.

Create a new gabby object using the Person constructor. She should have a job of "student" and her married property should be true.

```
var james = {
    // add properties to this object!
    this.job = "programmer";
    this.married = "false";
}

function Person(job, married) {
    this.job = job;
    this.married = married;
}

// create a "gabby" object using the Person constructor!
var gabby = new Person("student", "true");
```

Comment: Do we need to guess the error message? PS: I also recommend you to check your lectures about data types once again, especially about strings and booleans

Comment: Well "true" is not true and "false" is not false.

Comment: @epascarello: `"true"` is truthy though. That counts for something :) (However, `"false"` is not even falsy...)

Comment: Considering this is from a Codecademy lesson, why don't you just ask right there on the lesson's forums? The rules on those forums are much less strict than they are here ;)

Comment: @all can u guys give solution i tried but not able to fix it

Answer (score 1):

james syntax, you are trying to write statements directly in an object literal which you can't do.

Use `{ key: 'value'}` syntax

Should be:

```
var james = {
    // add properties to this object!
     job : "programmer",
     married : false
}
```

Or

```
var james ={};
james.job= "programmer";
```

or

```
var james = {};
james['job'] = "programmer";
```

Comment: While I'm joking in comments, a full answer should definitely address the `"false"` vs `false` issue...

Comment: There is no reason that his code won't work using "false" and "true", you know not what the rest of his code does. Having said that though I would make the change.

Comment: @Neilos it depends on the "work" term definition. If the task is to make it syntactically valid - one could just remove all the lines - an empty file is syntactically correct.

Comment: @Neilos: It will work, but will not work according to the spec (the job should be `"programmer"`, the married property should be `false`)

Comment: @Amadan more important my copy paste left in `;` after each value I forgot to remove

Comment: @Amadan Ok I concede :)

Comment: var james = {
    // add properties to this object!
    job : "programmer",
    married : false
},

function Person(job, married) {
    this.job = job;
    this.married = married;
}

// create a "gabby" object using the Person constructor!
var gabby = new Person("student", true);

Comment: @charlietfl: thanks for ur reply but till i see some error providing my code below var james = {
    // add properties to this object!
    job : "programmer",
    married : false
},

function Person(job, married) {
    this.job = job;
    this.married = married;
}

// create a "gabby" object using the Person constructor!
var gabby = new Person("student", true);

Comment: get rid of comma after object and use `;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var Person = function (job, married) {
    this.job = job;
    this.married = married;
}

var james = new Person("programmer", false);
var gabby = new Person("student", true);
```

Could you please try it again? Thanks.

Comment: it shows me this error Oops, try again. Make sure james has a married property with the boolean value false